# can you parameterized where clause in jpql

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpql

I'm not super familiar about JPQL, but I know you can parameterize a condition by doing something like:

```
 em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.firstName = :name)
               .setParameter("name","Bill");
```

Or:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.firstName= ?1)
              .setParameter(1,"Bill");
```

But can you parameterize something else? Say a criteria by parameterize a WHERE clause. For example can you do something like:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE :criteria = Bill)
                   .setParameter("criteria","p.lastName");
```

I test the code above but it doesn't work, so my question is: is there a way to parameterize a WHERE clause in JPQL. Or is there any other query language support WHERE clause parameterization? Lots of thanks!

Comment: Can you use [`Criteria API`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_criteria_api.htm)?

Comment: No, not using JPQL. Makes no sense. Use Criteria

Comment: I checked Criteria API but didn't find anything useful...Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.lastName = :lastName", Person.class);
query.setParameter("lastname", "Bill");
```

If you wish to add more parameters then

```
TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.lastName = :lastName AND p.firstName = :firstName", Person.class);
query.setParameter("lastName", "Bill");
query.setParameter("firstName", "Jack");
```

Once query is created, you can use

```
query.getResultList();
```

If you are expecting multiple results

or

```
query.getSingleResult();
```

If you expect only one result (Ex. querying by Primary Key or Unique Column)

> For more information, refer to [TypedQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html)

To answer the question from the comments:

a. Either have three query and use the query based on what they selected in the UI

```
String query;
if (isFirstName) {
    query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.firstName = :searchCriteria"
} else if (isMiddleName) {
    query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.middleName = :searchCriteria"
} else {
    query = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.lastName = :searchCriteria"
}
TypedQuery < Person > query = em.createQuery(query, Person.class);
query.setParameter("searchCriteria", "Bill");
```

b. Change the search:

```
String searchCriteria = "p.lastName";
TypedQuery<Person> query = em.createQuery(("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE " + searchCriteria + " = :name"), Person.class);
query.setParameter("name", "Bill");
```

*For string comparison, you can also use [LIKE](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string#LIKE_-_String_Pattern_Matching_with_Wildcards_)

Comment: Oh, what I meant is that I want to change the criteria of searching, i.e. the statement after WHERE clause...in your example, you still need to set up the WHERE clause before the runtime. but thanks anyway!

Comment: @ODStreet I am not quite sure I understand what you are trying to find. After WHERE, like an ORDER BY and LIMIT? Could you provide an example or pseudo code of what it is you are looking for

Comment: Criteria, by my definition, is the category you want to set conditions on. For example, a person can have firstName, lastName, middleName, and these are all criterias. Now I want to get a List<Person> based on someone called "Bill", but whether this "Bill" is a firstName, lastName or middleName is decided by the users in the runtime. So I have to writer a query something like "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE :xxName=Bill". In this example, xxName will be replaces with either p.firstName/p.lastName/p.middleName that provided by usrs. I have a psuedo code in my question.Thank you!

Comment: I updated the answer, hope that helps with what you require

Comment: Thank you! Seemed like there is no out of box API for implementing this criteria parameterization. So your way will be one of the solutions at this time. I will set yours as answer. Thank you!